# PHP read .txt file and create an array

Tags: php

i need read a .txt file and create an array for get values.

I mainly want to do it in php, but I accept other suggestions

[Slot000] can be as many as people are inside the server (001, 002, 003... 010,011...)

The .txt file updates every 5 seconds.

Thanks for help me!

Example of code:

```
[Server]
ServerPLR=DedicatedServer
LobbyName=xFactorracing.com V8 OR
ModName=V8Factor Unleashed 2012 v1.1
Aids=0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,3

[Session]
Scene=Queensland International Raceway
TrackAIW=Queensland.AIW
TrackLength=3134.0745
StartTime=2013-08-09 05:26:27
LengthLaps=-1
LengthTime=90
DarkCloud=0.00
Raining=0.00
AmbientTemp=24.8
TrackTemp=24.3
OnPathWetness=0.00
OffPathWetness=0.00
SessionTime=1.005314
Session=Practice1
GamePhase=Preparing
YellowFlag=None
SectorYellowFlags=(0,0,0)
FCY_log=()

[Slot000]
Driver=daniel
Vehicle=Unknown
VehicleClass=Unknown
IsAI=1
Position=1
Laps=0
InSector=1
BestLap=-1.000
LastLap=-1.000
BestSectors=(-1.000, -1.000, -1.000)
LastLapSectors=(-1.000, -1.000, -1.000)
Sectors=(-1.000, -1.000, -1.000)
Pitstops=0
InPits=1
TimeGapToLider=0.000
LapGapToLider=0
TimeGapToPrev=0.000
LapGapToPrev=0
LapDistanceTravelled=-1.069
FinishStatus=None

[END]
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with `C#` and `C++`?

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)

Comment: I mainly want to do it in php, but I accept other suggestions

Comment: That's an ini file. [PHP has a method for reading such a file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)

Comment: Thanks, i am a noob... Sry..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text file follows the `php.ini` format/structure, so you can conveniently use the `parse_ini_` functions ([see manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-string.php)), instead of writing a custom parser. The line `FCY_log=()` throws an error though, `()` (empty brackets) isn't acceptable syntax, so we're doing a bit of preprocessing before parsing the string. It's still simple enough:

```
$raw = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$raw = str_replace('=()', '=', $raw); // fixing the offending value
$data = parse_ini_string($raw, true, INI_SCANNER_TYPED);
var_dump($data);
```

If there were no syntax anomalies, you could simply use `parse_ini_file('file.txt')` instead. In any case, this produces an associative array, as follows:

```
array(4) {
    ["Server"] · array(4) {
        ["ServerPLR"] · string(15) "DedicatedServer"
        ["LobbyName"] · string(23) "xFactorracing.com V8 OR"
        ["ModName"] · string(28) "V8Factor Unleashed 2012 v1.1"
        ["Aids"] · string(21) "0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,3"
    }
    ["Session"] · array(18) {
        ["Scene"] · string(32) "Queensland International Raceway"
        ["TrackAIW"] · string(14) "Queensland.AIW"
        ["TrackLength"] · float(3134.0745)
        ["StartTime"] · string(19) "2013-08-09 05:26:27"
        ["LengthLaps"] · int(-1)
        ["LengthTime"] · int(90)
    ...
```

Since there can be several slots, presumably having keys with identical names, we are using the `process_sections` option, `parse_ini_string($raw, **true**)`, which yields a multidimensional array grouped by section headings. We're also using the `INI_SCANNER_TYPED` flag; without it, all values would be of "string" type. (Which may or may not matter in your use case.)

Comment: This solution return an error "=" expectate on line 2... Any idea?

Comment: Are you using the exact code I gave above (except the filename), and the sample data you provided? If you have a variation of the data, it's possible that line 2 of the data being parsed is also not compatible with "php.ini syntax" (which is a pretty standard [INI file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file)). Please post the relevant lines that cause the error. It seems like there's a stand-alone string. Each line should be either a `[section head]` or a `key=value` pair, or a `; comment` (or empty).

Comment: Yes, text file have comment on first line, i delete this. Thanks